# String interpolation with subhashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my code I want to use string interpolation for an email subject I am generating.

```
output = "this is my %{title}" % {title: "Text here"}
```

This works as expected, but is there a way to use hashes inside of hashes and still be able to use string interpolation?

It would be awesome if I could do something like:

```
output = "this is my %{title.text}" % {title: {text: "text here"}}
```

Comment: That's not string interpolation, that's just a call to the [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-25) method using operator syntax.

Comment: Looks strange. Have you tried `%{title[:text]}`?

Comment: to add to @sschmeck comment.... `.` notation does not work on `hash`es....

Comment: Unfortunately `title[:text]` doesn't work with `%` method as it will look for `title[:text]` key in the hash.

Comment: Thanks, your comments made me decide to go with a Liquid template instead. https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/

Comment: @PetrGazarov Good to know. The hash behaves like named arguments for the substituion string. Thanks.

Comment: I have asked that as a feature on Ruby core, but Matz is negative on that: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10130.

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby 2.3, `sprintf` checks the hash's default value, so you could provide a [`default_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) to [`dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) up the nested value:

```
hash = {title: {text: "text here"}}
hash.default_proc = proc { |h, k| h.dig(*k.to_s.split('.').map(&:to_sym)) }

"this is my %{title.text}" % hash
#=> "this is my text here"
```

Kind of hacky, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible with `%` method. You'd have to use regular Ruby interpolation with `"#{}"`.
I'd also point out that you can use [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html).

```
title = OpenStruct.new(text: 'text here')

output = "this is my #{title.text}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not hard to make this work if you write a simple utility method to "squash" a nested Hash's keys, e.g.:

```
def squash_hash(hsh, stack=[])
  hsh.reduce({}) do |res, (key, val)|
    next_stack = [ *stack, key ]
    if val.is_a?(Hash)
      next res.merge(squash_hash(val, next_stack))
    end
    res.merge(next_stack.join(".").to_sym => val)
  end
end

hsh = { foo: { bar: 1, baz: { qux: 2 } }, quux: 3 }

p squash_hash(hsh)
# => { :"foo.bar" => 1, :"foo.baz.qux" => 2, :quux => 3 }

puts <<END % squash_hash(hsh)
foo.bar: %{foo.bar}
foo.baz.qux: %{foo.baz.qux}
quux: %{quux}
END
# => foo.bar: 1
#    foo.baz.qux: 2
#    quux: 3
```